# Getting HTTP post data on defined url (asp.net web form)

Tags: asp.net, http

I am creating an asp.net (web form application) In which I have to http post some value to payment provider and in return payment provider will return my application some value using http post. but to notification_url submitted by my first request

I know I can use Request.Form.AllKeys. but where to put this code on pageload and how to redirect etc...

account id: 
        
        notification_url: 
        
        start_date: 
        
        amount: 
        
        first name: 
        
        last_name:

Comment: <form action="http://demo.paypal.com/default.aspx" method="post">
        account id: <input type="text" id="account_id" name="account_id" value="1234" />
        <br />
        notification_url: <input type="url" id="notification_url" name="notification_url" value=https://index.aspx />
        <br />
        start_date: <input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="23102015" />
        <br />
        amount: <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="10" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

Comment: You don't redirect. Instead use `HttpWebRequest` to make your own HTTP request to the payment processor.